# why kafka ingestion service of druid cannot have 2 datasources

Tags: apache-kafka, druid, data-ingestion

I used druid indexing service to ingest kafka data, when I created one datasource, it works well. But when I added another datasource, there are no tasks to assign for the second datasource.How should I do make all datasources can work well?there are 2 datasources below.

[image]

But running tasks are all about "inhouse_homepage" datasource.and the work capacity(cores - 1) are all for "inhouse_homepage" datasource.Please help me.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had solve the problem by myself, just to change the ingestion json configuration, **segmentGranularity** is set from MINUTE to HOUR, **taskCount** is set equals to partition of kafka consumer, **replicas** is set to 1.